# Simplest Dialog/Message Box for beginners?

Tags: java, dialog

I am unsure of how to do this. I am in a intro to java class and it asks us to use a message box (instead of just system.out.println) I remember we imported something and it was an easy change, but I am unable to find any notes on it.

Furthermore all examples I've found across the web and this site are taking it beyond the scope of this class.

I apologize in advance if this is an incorrect format, this is my first time posting here.

TLDR: Trying to change

```
    System.out.print("Enter renter name: ");
    renterName = input.next();
```

to appear in a message box instead of in the Eclipse Console

I know we imported something (same way we import Scanner) to make this work, but every example I find is essentially saying create your own dialog box methods which is beyond my scope of knowledge, and this class.

COMPLETE CODE IS FOLLOWS:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RentYourVideo {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    int numberOfRentals, finalBill;

    VideoRental rental = new VideoRental(); //runs constructor
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String renterName;

    System.out.print("Enter renter name: ");
    renterName = input.next();

    System.out.print("Enter number of videos to rent: ");
    numberOfRentals = input.nextInt();

    rental.setRentalFee();  //needs to set rental fee to $5 according to assignment
    rental.calculateBill(numberOfRentals);  //from prev input
    finalBill = rental.getFinalBill();

    System.out.println(renterName + " your total bill for " +numberOfRentals+ " videos is $" +finalBill);

    input.close();
  }
}
```

//CHANGE ALL PROMPTS & OUTPUT TO DIALOG/MESSAGE BOX!!!!

```
public class VideoRental {

  private int rentalFee, finalBill, numberOfRentals;

  public VideoRental() {    //constructor method
    rentalFee = 0;
    finalBill = 0;
  }

  public void setRentalFee() {  //set method
    rentalFee = 5;
  }     //the assignment claims this must set rentalFee = 5

  public void calculateBill(int inRented) {
    numberOfRentals = inRented;
    finalBill = rentalFee * numberOfRentals;
  }

  public int getFinalBill() {
    return finalBill;
  }

}
```

Comment: Do you remember which GUI toolkit you were using? Swing, SWT, AWT, JavaFX?

Comment: I don't think I've ever used any of those. I am in the final week of a ITP 120, and we just began using OO. From my knowledge we simply did an import.Java.util.Scanner; style of operation to make this work.

Comment: Go ask one of your fellow students then. You'll need some kind of UI library to create a dialog window. Furthermore, I doubt that a single import will fix all your problems. It's more likely that you have to create an entire window (or used a pre-defined skeleton). It does not make any sense for us to guess what you *might perhaps have used*.

Comment: Since this is Eclipse, OP is most likely using SWT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out:

```
String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter name here:");
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

[...]

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int numberOfRentals, finalBill;

    VideoRental rental = new VideoRental(); //runs constructor

    String renterName;
    renterName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter renter name: ");

    numberOfRentals = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter number of videos to rent: "));

    rental.setRentalFee();  //needs to set rental fee to $5 according to assignment
    rental.calculateBill(numberOfRentals);  //from prev input
    finalBill = rental.getFinalBill();

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, renterName + " your total bill for " +numberOfRentals+ " videos is $" +finalBill);
  }
```

Comment: Can this be used in eclipse? I must be doing something wrong.

Its basically asking me to create a JoptionPane class

Comment: @Kierwynn The IDE is irrelevant. What error are you getting?

Comment: Done, sorry from my casual browsing here I've never seen anyone submit full code.

Comment: new error, might not be code related. i was having trouble installing java on this machine so maybe its still wonky I'll try from school computers, thank you again for help: 

Access restriction: The type 'JOptionPane' is not API (restriction on required library 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar')